# undefined reference to `` CLion

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, clion

I am trying to compile a project in the CLION IDE and I can't succeed but I can compile the exact same files in Eclipse. 
First this is the error:

```
CMakeFiles\Besart.dir/objects.a(library1.cpp.obj): In function `Init':
C:/Users/Besart/ClionProjects/Besart/Data Structures 1/HW 2/library1.cpp:17: 
undefined reference to `DataStructure::DataStructure()'
```

Now I have included the requested files, for example in the source file of library1.cpp
I have:

```
#include "library1.h"
#include "DataStructure.h"
void* Init() {
    DataStructure* DS(nullptr);
     try {
       DS = new DataStructure();
      } catch (std::bad_alloc &e) {
       delete DS;
       return nullptr;
        }
      return (void *)DS;
}
```

but the file is implemented in DataStructures.cpp and declared in DataStructure.h
[See image!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2G2d.jpg)

Finally this is the CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Besart)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 )
set(SOURCE_FILES  "Data Structures 1/HW 2/main.cpp"
    "Data Structures 1/HW 2/Creature.cpp" "Data Structures 1/HW 2/Magi.cpp"
    "Data Structures 1/HW 2/DataStructure.cpp/"
    "Data Structures 1/HW 2/library1.cpp")

add_executable(Besart ${SOURCE_FILES}  "Data Structures 1/HW 2/main.cpp"
    "Data Structures 1/HW 2/Creature.cpp"
     "Data Structures 1/HW 2/Magi.cpp"
    "Data Structures 1/HW 2/DataStructure.cpp/"
     "Data Structures 1/HW 2/library1.cpp")
```

[CMAKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d905c.jpg)

Can someone see the problem and help me compile this project in CLion?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a definition for `DataStructure`'s default constructor anywhere? (Don't post pictures of text; post the text.)

Comment: BTW: if you can't come up with a better name than "DataStructure" for a data structure, its purpose is probably not very well-defined.

Comment: ***"Data Structures 1/HW 2/DataStructure.cpp/"*** is wrong. Don't put a slash at the end of the line.

Comment: Also change your add_executable() to `add_executable(Besart ${SOURCE_FILES})` no need to repeat what is in `${SOURCE_FILES}`

Comment: Don't use `-std=c++11` when using CMake 3.x. Use `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)`. CMake will figure out the appropriate compiler flags automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an errant / after `DataStructure.cpp` here:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES  "Data Structures 1/HW 2/main.cpp"
    "Data Structures 1/HW 2/Creature.cpp" "Data Structures 1/HW 2/Magi.cpp"
    "Data Structures 1/HW 2/DataStructure.cpp/"
    "Data Structures 1/HW 2/library1.cpp")
```

change this to:

```
  set(SOURCE_FILES  "Data Structures 1/HW 2/main.cpp"
        "Data Structures 1/HW 2/Creature.cpp" "Data Structures 1/HW 2/Magi.cpp"
        "Data Structures 1/HW 2/DataStructure.cpp"
        "Data Structures 1/HW 2/library1.cpp")
```

then fix your add_executable() in the following way:

```
add_executable(Besart ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

no need to repeat the content of `${SOURCE_FILES}`.

Comment: This was the problem, it was a typo.Thank you very much.